# How can I send object to unrelated component through a service in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, service, components

So I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to send an object from component1 to component2 using a service. When I log the result to the console in component2, it doesn't give me the updated value of the object and it's probably because the service is reinitialized in the second component. Can you help on this issue?

This is my code

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CodeServiceService {
  codeInfo:Code={
    name:"",
    text:"",
    type:0
  };
  getCode(){
    console.log(this.codeInfo);
    return this.codeInfo;
  }
  setCode(result:Code){
    this.codeInfo=result;
  }
}
```

Component1

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-newscan',
  templateUrl: './newscan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newscan.component.css'],
  providers:[CodeServiceService]
})
export class NewscanComponent implements OnInit {
scannedCode:Code={
    name:"name",
    text:"text",
    type:1
  };

  constructor(private service:CodeServiceService){}
saveInfo(){
    this.service.setCode(this.scannedCode);
  }
}
```

Component2

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-scan-list',
  templateUrl: './scan-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scan-list.component.css'],
  providers:[CodeServiceService]
})

export class ScanListComponent implements OnInit {

  newcode:Code={
    name:"",
    text:"",
    type:0
  };
constructor(private service:CodeServiceService){
  }
  ngOnInit(){

    this.newcode=this.service.getCode();
console.log(this.newcode);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the service from the `providers` array. You have already provided this in the `root`

Comment: Check my answer and feel free to upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using

```
 providers:[CodeServiceService]
```

in both components, so it's creating new instance of service for both components.

use `providers:[CodeServiceService]` in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
   // ..... imports
    providers:[CodeServiceService]
   //..
})
```

**In Angular 6:**

you can use below code in `service.ts`, rather than adding in `app.module.ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

Comment: If `providedIn: 'root'` is defined, you don't need to put it in the `providers` array of the module.

Comment: From Angular 6 onwards `providedIn: 'root'` makes it available to the entire app. No need of `providers` in app.module

Answer (score 0):

you can use rxjs subject for that here is the example.

1./ Service

```
 import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
 @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class CodeServiceService {
 codeInfo:Code={
    name:"",
    text:"",
    type:0
 };
 getCode() : Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
setCode(result:Code){
   this.subject.next({ text: code });
}
```

}

2./ component1

```
 export class NewscanComponent implements OnInit {
 scannedCode:Code={
   name:"name",
   text:"text",
 type:1
 };

 constructor(private service:CodeServiceService){}
 saveInfo(){
   this.service.setCode(this.scannedCode);
 }
}
```

3./ component2

```
export class ScanListComponent implements OnInit {
 newcode:Code={
   name:"",
   text:"",
   type:0
};
constructor(private service:CodeServiceService){
}
ngOnInit(){
 this.newcode=this.service.getCode().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response); // here you can get updated data from another component  
 });
 }
}
```

You can implement this method for sending data to a component which doesn't have a parent-child relationship.